# Copy iOS Library Music over Videos Allowed in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, audio

I am working on an iOS video editing app, and looking into any limitations of putting audio over the video.  So my question is, if it possible(are we allowed to) use songs or clips from songs in the music library? Will this kind of feature get rejected when being submitted to the app store?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant see a problem with this - Its no different to DJ apps on the App Store reading music and allowing the user to edit them. The only issue is if user was to push to YouTube etc then issues may occur

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will accept the answer, after I download and test a DJ app that can do this. thank you.